# Did the Bing Maps Geocode SOAP API move? I'm getting a 404 Error

Tags: soap, wsdl, bing-maps

I support a legacy app that references a wsdl here:

http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.svc?wsdl

Which seems up-to-date, based on this documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd221354.aspx#Anchor_4

I'm getting a 404 error visiting that URL. Anyone know if it's moved recently or just deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bing maps SOAP services were announced to be deprecated in 2016 and official end of life was June 2017, so it's surprising that it was still working for you.
You should use the REST services which replaced the SOAP services more than 6 years ago. REST service documentation is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx and there's a migration guide here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/discontinued-control-migration-guidelines